# Assigning an Integer to variant

Tags: c++, winapi, variant

I want to set Flag as [`navOpenInBackgroundTab` of `BrowserNavConstants enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which soon will be passed as parameter to [`IWebBrowser2::Navigate2` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Signature of `IWebBrowser2::Navigate2`:-

```
HRESULT Navigate2(
    VARIANT *URL,
    VARIANT *Flags,
    VARIANT *TargetFrameName,
    VARIANT *PostData,
    VARIANT *Headers
);
```

This is where I have problem:-

```
VARIANT SITE={0}, vFlags = {0},vTargetFrameName = {0},vPostData = {0},vHeaders = {0};
...
...
vFlags.intVal=navOpenInBackgroundTab;//<--Here,Don't know how to do it.Not Working..

m_spWebBrowser->Navigate2(&SITE, &vFlags,&vTargetFrameName, &vPostData, &vHeaders);
```

Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`InitVariantFromInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):-

```
HRESULT hr = InitVariantFromInt32(navOpenInBackgroundTab, &vFlags);
```

You can also use (From my old codebase :) ) :-

```
V_VT(&vFlags) = VT_I4;
V_I4(&vFlags) = navOpenInBackgroundTab;
```